# Array creates validation error in ASP.NET 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-6.0

I noticed a validation error when changing my WebApi project to use .NET 6 instead of .NET Core 3.1 for my array query parameter types. Previously they didn't return a validation error, but with 6.0 they do.

I have the following class for a query:

```cs
public class Query
{
    public List<string> Id { get; set; }
}
```

And a controller with the following endpoint:

```cs
[HttpGet()]
public IActionResult Get([FromQuery] Test2 test)
{
    return Ok()
}
```

When I send a query without any query parameters, I get a **BadRequest** marking the field id as required, when implemented using .NET 6. When using .NET Core 3.1 (or 5.0), the method executes correctly.

For reproduction I have created an ASP.NET Core WebApi project both with .NET Core 3.1, 5.0 and 6.0 and added a controller endpoint with a Query-Entity containing a string array as in the example above without any other changes.

Frankly I'm a bit stumped with this one. I tried to execute the Validator for the System.ComponentModel manually, but this yielded in the expected result (no error). I didn't add anything to the scaffold which would account for this behavior, it's basically identical. I didn't find any mention of this in the list of breaking changes for .NET 6.0 as well.

Adding a custom Validation Attribute ("NotRequired") to the Id property fixes the behavior, I would however prefer to be able to keep the query model as-is as it worked previously and the ComponentModel doesn't show any errors.

Comment: Default property values often change when Microsoft releases new Net/Core libraries.  There isn't much you can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#non-nullable-reference-types-and-required-attribute):

> The validation system treats non-nullable parameters or bound properties as if they had a `[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]` attribute. By enabling Nullable contexts, MVC implicitly starts validating non-nullable properties or parameters as if they had been attributed with the `[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]` attribute.

You can make the property to be nullable reference type so it will make `Id` optional:

```cs
public class Query
{
    public List<string>? Id { get; set; }
}
```

Or you can completely disable nullable context analysis which will also revert to the old behaviour (so personally I would recommend against it).